# trying to pull UNIX_TIMECODE from database column, Code keeps throwing the start of UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php

this is the code I have pulling UNIX_TIMECODE in a column called "created_date" from a table called "message_control", for some reason it pull the origin of UNIX_TIME; "1970-01-01 00:00:00".

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "changeme";
$dbname = "time";
$date = "created_date";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from message_control";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<h5>" . $row["subject"] . "</h5><p>" .
    $row["body"] . "</p><h5>" .
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date) ) . "</h5>";
  }
}
```

Comment: The $date variable is set to "created_date"

Answer (score 2):

`$date` is set to the string `"created_date"`, which is not a valid time format. As such, `strtotime()` is converting it to `FALSE`, which `date()` is interpreting as the UNIX timestamp 0.

You probably mean either `$row["date"]` or `$row["created_date"]`, not `$date`.

Comment: "Created_date" is the name of the column I want to pull the date from, if I do what you suggest it pulls the number, but I want it converted into a readable format.

Comment: That's what the `date()` function does…